# Make absolute positioned div cover the viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a jQuery animation that have a absolute positioned div that is generated on a specific location of the viewport (`left: 150px`) and this div grows vertically and horizontally, covering the entire viewport

But unfortunately, the div is overflowing the viewport, and not covering the entire screen

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 function generateChild(top, bottom, left, right) {
  $("#divGenerator").append(`
   <div style="top:${top};bottom:${bottom};left:${left};right:${right};" class="child"></div>
  `);
 }

 generateChild("50vh", "0", "80vw", "0");

 /*
 setInterval(function() {
  $(".child").animate({
   "transform": "translate3d(0, 0, 0)",
   "transition": "all 0.5s ease-out"
  }, 3000, function() {
   $(this).fadeOut().remove();
  });
 }, 1000);
 */
})
```

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}

#divGenerator {
 position: relative;
 height: 100vh;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 margin: auto;
 background-color: black;
 border: 1px solid black;
}

.child {
 position: absolute;
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Trippy Waves</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>

 <div id="divGenerator"></div>

 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does it need to cover the entire viewport or without that 150px on the left? can you provide a working snippet?

Comment: the 150px on the left is absolutely needed, i just added a working snippet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to achieve this effect you need several conditions:

- use `position:fixed` (not `absolute`), so your element is positioned relative to the viewport, not to its closest relatively positioned parent.
- get the initial `top`, `left`, `width` and `height` from the [`.getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) of the element you're starting from. Note this method is defined on the DOM element, not on the jQuery wrapper (so you'll need `$(selector).get(0).getBoundingClientRect()`)
- animate from those positions towards: `top:0;left:0;width:100vw;height:100vh`.

In this particular example you don't need `getBoundingClientRect()`, because you generate your element from arbitrary data (from you function) - but normally you want it as it gets position of an element *relative to current position of viewport* (including scroll, etc...).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    function generateChild(top, bottom, left, right) {
        $("#divGenerator").append(`
            <div style="top:${top};bottom:${bottom};left:${left};right:${right};" class="child"></div>
        `);
    }

    generateChild("50vh", "0", "80vw", "0");

    setInterval(function() {
        $(".child").animate({
            "width": "100vw",
            "height": "100vh",
           "top":0,
           "left":0
        }, 3000, function() {
            $(this).fadeOut().remove();
        });
    }, 1000);
})
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#divGenerator {
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: black;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.child {
    position: fixed;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Trippy Waves</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="divGenerator"></div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Personal advice:** don't use `.animate()`. Use [velocity](http://velocityjs.org/).